# Download pdf using remote method

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, loopbackjs, strongloop

I intend to download a dynamically generated pdf file using a remote method, the file exists at a particular path and I am using return type "file". My implementation is:

```
customer.downloadFile = function downloadFile(userId, res, cb){
    var reader = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../document.pdf');
    cb(null, reader, 'application/pdf');
};

customer.remoteMethod(
    'downloadFile',
    {
        isStatic: true,
        accepts: [
            { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true },
            { arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': { source: 'res' } }
        ],
        returns: [
            { arg: 'body', type: 'file', root: true },
            { arg: 'Content-Type', type: 'string', http: { target: 'header' } }
        ],
        http: {path: '/:id/downloadFile', verb: 'get'}
    }
);
```

The issue with the above code is that the browser although displays the beautiful pdf file container, but instead of the file following error is shown:

[image]

Please point out as to what is wrong with the code and how to correct.
Got lead from this URL: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-swagger/issues/34

Comment: Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"  // goes in header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got that working with following:

```
fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, fileData) {
    res.contentType("application/pdf");
    res.status(200).send(fileData);

    if (!err) {
        fs.unlink(fileName);
    }
    else {
        cb(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: where is `res` defined?

Comment: @user3568719 sorry for late reply, i have modified the question to include the res support

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`loopback-component-storage`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage) to manage downloadable files.

Files are grouped in so-called containers (Basically, a folder with a single level of hierarchy, not more).

How it is done:

1. Create a model called `container` for instance.
2. Create a `storage` datasource that uses as `connector` the `loopback-component-storage`
3. Give to `container` model the datasource `storage`

That's it. You can upload and download files to/from your container.
With a container, you can store files to a local filesystem, or move later to Cloud solutions.